# Finding answer for a set of nonlinear matrix equations

Tags: matrix-equations, nonlinear-optimization

I have a set of matrix equation as described below:

1-A*P=P*X
2-b=P*y

In above equations, *A* and *b* are known matrices of size *n* by *n* and *n* by *1* respectively. *P*, *X* and *y* are unknown matrices of size *n* by *r*, *r* by *r* and *r* by 1  of appropriate sizes. Also we know that *r*<<*n* (r is much smaller than n).

I also know that first equation has an answer iff *Im(AP)* is subset of *Im(P)* and likewise, second equation has answer iff *b* is a subset of *Im(P)*. 
Now, the hope is that we can select (design) *P* such that above conditions are satisfied; then finding *X* and *y* is possible by using conventional algorithms.

Just as a hint, suppose that equation (1) was the only constraint; by choosing columns of *P* as eigen vectors of *A* we can easily compute the exact answer; however, adding the equation (2), if *b* cannot be expressed as linear combination of eigen vectors of *A* equality cannot be satisfied (best answer for equation (2) would be Least Squares output which doesn't result in exact equality necessarily).

So, in brief, I'm looking for a systematic way to design *P* (with respect to above conditions) such that I know that *X* and *y* exist.

Comment: Can you freely choose $X$ and $y$? Because then you could set, in block matrix notation, $P = (b \, P')$ and use $y = (1 \, 0 \, 0 \, \ldots)^T$, so that $X = P^+ \, A \, P$ for any left-inverse $P^+$, where the reduced matrix $P'$ is arbitrary as long as $P$ has full rank.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion; this choice of _P_ will result in satisfaction of second equality constraints, since _b_ is a subset of _Im(P)_; using the pseudo inverse does not satisfy first equality constraints unless for the selected _P_ and _Im(AP)_ is a subset of _Im(P)_.

Comment: but yes; we can freely choose X and y as long as conditions are satisfied.

Comment: You are, of course, correct: A _right-inverse_ is needed s.t. $PX = P P^+ A P = A P$!

Comment: The point is that, here, it is not possible to say _P*P_inv=I_.

Comment: While off course _P_inv*P=I_. This because of the fact that P is only full column rank; please correct me if it doesn't make sense.